# Making directory with vitual studio 2012 coding in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Good evening everyone, please I'm writing a Library management application in c++ using virtual studio 2012. I had already writing some codes using Dev c++ it worked but when I switched to visual studio it gives error. It involves creating folders and  checking if the folders were actually created. That is using dir and mkdir.

Comment: Ok. Thanks guys I"ll try to use both and see which works best for me. I'll let u guys know how it goes. Thanks once again.

Comment: Please what does minus one mean beside the post

Comment: It means someone didn't think this was a good question for some reason. It is customary to state the reason here in the comments, but it is not required.

Comment: OK. Thanks alot @ metal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot guys but I found this that solved my problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void main( void )
{
   if( _mkdir( "\\testtmp" ) == 0 )
   {
      printf( "Directory '\\testtmp' was successfully created\n" );
      system( "dir \\testtmp" );
      if( _rmdir( "\\testtmp" ) == 0 )
        printf( "Directory '\\testtmp' was successfully removed\n"  );
      else
         printf( "Problem removing directory '\\testtmp'\n" );
   }
   else
      printf( "Problem creating directory '\\testtmp'\n" );
   int a;
   cin >> a;
}
```

the cin >> a; is just to keep the output screen so I can see the result

Answer (score 2):

Windows and Linux (POSIX) don't support the same API for most file system functions. You can use Microsoft's platform-specific APIs like [`CreateDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855(v=vs.85).aspx) or use the POSIX-like versions like [`_mkdir()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you have a more recent C++ compiler / standard library, you can use the [experimental filesystem library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) that is slated to become part of standard C++, perhaps as early as C++17. If not, you can use [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) from which the pre-standard experimental library was drawn.

Here's a complete, minimal example using Boost.Filesystem, which will work on both Windows and Linux without modification:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    if( !fs::exists( "my_dir" ) )
    {
        if( fs::create_directory( "my_dir" ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Directory created!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

See it run: <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f67f722b6187f78)</kbd>.

Here's the same code but with `std::experimental::filesystem`: <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa6fe873f98ff7ce)</kbd>.

You would need the appropriate include and linker paths setup in your build system for either of these to work locally. The biggest "gotcha" using the filesystem is that it throws exceptions for a lot of errors by default. You can either setup `try`/`catch` blocks at the appropriate places or pass in an error code param to make it return the status there instead.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but my problem is that it worked on Dev C++ but why not on Visual studio. I"ll try to post the code

Comment: @Maxfurry: I don't see the code. But I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the example I could not put the code it said it was too long

Comment: What said the code was too long? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The only thing I would add is that create_directory can throw. So try-catch or pass a boost::system::error_code object

Comment: @lakeweb: Agreed. I had tried to cover that in my last paragraph.

Comment: @metal I'm sorry, yes you did! I did not see it in the code and did not read carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    if (!CreateDirectoryA("C:\\ABC123", NULL))
    {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
        {
            printf("Already Exists");
        }else if (GetLastError()== ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            printf("Path not found");
        }
    }else{
        printf("Created..");
    }
}
```

simple function will do.